# OpenGl selection and shaders ( for lighting) Crash on certain GPU (mostly ati)

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl

I got a little problem here with opengl selection and shaders.

We are using shaders for phong lighting. The shaders work just fine. But if we use our opengl picking combined with our shaders the app crashes. The combination works fine on more than 5 computers ( Geforce gtx 460 SE, Ati Mobility Radeon HD 5850, Intel Graphic 4000 etc...). But for some obscure reasons we crash with these errors:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000000cde9cc3, pid=2888, tid=3940
#
# JRE version: 7.0_07-b10
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.3-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd64.dll+0x6d9cc3]  ShCompile+0x17b3b3
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Projet2\Exe\hs_err_pid2888.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

It Looks like the compilation isn't working. On a working computer we have no compile error (using glGetShaderInfoLog).

The same thing happens on an AMD Radeon HD 6970M but the error is related to atixxxx.dll.

Here's our opengl selection:

```
GLint viewport[4];
glSelectBuffer(BUFSIZE,selectBuf);
glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,viewport);
gluPickMatrix(x,viewport[3]-y, 5,5,viewport);

FacadeModele::obtenirInstance()->obtenirVue()->obtenirProjection()->appliquer();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glInitNames();

glLoadIdentity();
FacadeModele::obtenirInstance()->obtenirVue()->obtenirCamera().positionner();

arbre->afficher();
int hits;

// restorer la matrice originale
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glFlush();

// retourner au mode de rendering normal
hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);

if (hits > 0)
    processHits(hits,selectBuf);
```

Our vertex shader :

```
varying vec3 normal, lightDir1, lightDir2, lightDir3, eyeVec;
void main()
{
// calculer la normale qui sera interpolée pour le nuanceur de fragment
normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;

// calculer la position du sommet dans l'espace de la caméra ("eye-coordinate position")
vec3 ecPosition = vec3( gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex );

// vecteur de la direction de la lumière
lightDir1 = vec3( gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - ecPosition );
lightDir2 = vec3( gl_LightSource[1].position.xyz - ecPosition );
lightDir3 = vec3( gl_LightSource[2].position.xyz - ecPosition );

eyeVec = -ecPosition; // vecteur qui pointe vers le (0,0,0), c'est-à-dire vers l'oeil
gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
// transformation standard du sommet (ModelView et Projection)
gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

Our fragment shader:

```
varying vec3 normal, lightDir1, lightDir2, lightDir3, eyeVec;
float maxCutoff = 0.9;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 couleur = ( ( gl_FrontLightModelProduct.sceneColor * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient ) +
                    ( gl_LightSource[0].ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient ) +
                    ( gl_LightSource[1].ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient ) 
                );
    // vecteur normal
    vec3 N = normalize( normal );
    // direction de la lumière
    vec3 L = normalize( lightDir1 );
    // produit scalaire pour le calcul de la réflexion diffuse
    float NdotL = dot( N, L );

    vec3 D = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].spotDirection);
    float LdotD = dot(-L,D);
    float attenuation = (LdotD - maxCutoff)/(gl_LightSource[0].spotCosCutoff-maxCutoff)  ;

    // calcul de l'éclairage seulement si le produit scalaire est positif
    if ( NdotL > 0.0 )
    {
        // calcul de la composante diffuse
        if(attenuation > 0.0)
            couleur += gl_LightSource[0].diffuse * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * NdotL*attenuation;

        // calcul de la composante spéculaire
        vec3 E = normalize( eyeVec );
        vec3 R = -reflect( L, N ); // réflexion de L par rapport à N
        // produit scalaire pour la réflexion spéculaire
        float NdotHV = max( dot( R, E ), 0.0 );
        couleur += gl_LightSource[0].specular * gl_FrontMaterial.specular * pow( NdotHV, gl_FrontMaterial.shininess )*attenuation;
    }

    // vecteur normal
    vec3 N2 = normalize( normal );
    // direction de la lumière
    vec3 L2 = normalize( lightDir2 );
    // produit scalaire pour le calcul de la réflexion diffuse
    float NdotL2 = dot( N2, L2 );

    vec3 D2 = normalize(gl_LightSource[1].spotDirection);
    float LdotD2 = dot(-L2,D2);
    float attenuation2 = (LdotD2 - maxCutoff)/(gl_LightSource[1].spotCosCutoff-maxCutoff)  ;

    // calcul de l'éclairage seulement si le produit scalaire est positif
    if ( NdotL2 > 0.0 )
    {
        // calcul de la composante diffuse
        if(attenuation2 > 0.0)
            couleur += gl_LightSource[1].diffuse * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * NdotL2*attenuation2;

        // calcul de la composante spéculaire
        vec3 E2 = normalize( eyeVec );
        vec3 R2 = -reflect( L2, N2 ); // réflexion de L par rapport à N
        // produit scalaire pour la réflexion spéculaire
        float NdotHV2 = max( dot( R2, E2 ), 0.0 );
    }

    // vecteur normal
    vec3 N3 = normalize( normal );
    // direction de la lumière
    vec3 L3 = normalize( lightDir3 );
    // produit scalaire pour le calcul de la réflexion diffuse
    float NdotL3 = dot( N3, L3 );

    vec3 D3 = normalize(gl_LightSource[2].spotDirection);
    float LdotD3 = dot(-L3,D3);
    float attenuation3 = (LdotD3 - maxCutoff)/(gl_LightSource[2].spotCosCutoff-maxCutoff)  ;

    // calcul de l'éclairage seulement si le produit scalaire est positif
    if ( NdotL3 > 0.0 )
    {
        // calcul de la composante diffuse
        if(attenuation3 > 0.0)
            couleur += gl_LightSource[2].diffuse * gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * NdotL3*attenuation3;

        // calcul de la composante spéculaire
        vec3 E3 = normalize( eyeVec );
        vec3 R3 = -reflect( L3, N3 ); // réflexion de L par rapport à N
        // produit scalaire pour la réflexion spéculaire
        float NdotHV3 = max( dot( R3, E3 ), 0.0 );
    }

    couleur *= gl_Color;
    gl_FragColor = couleur;
}
```

Comment: Did you try channel 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use OpenGL selection mode together with shaders? If so, this is probably your problem: The selection mode likely triggers fallback into software implementation; I know of no OpenGL implementation that does selection mode on the GPU. Since this code path is so seldomly used, it's very likely that it's bug ridden. Especially if used together with shaders, which must be emulated on the GPU then. If the shader JIT compiler emits buggy code you'll get a crash.

To top things, the selection mode has been removed from newer OpenGL versions alltogether. Instead of selection mode (which is error prone and slow), you should instead render to a Framebuffer Object with a single channel integer color buffer attachment. Each object is rendered in a different "index" color. By reading back the index image you can do selection based on the pixel values. This can actually be combined with the selection projection matrix to limit fragment generation to a small subset of the view volume.

Comment: yes we're using them together. The use of opengl selection is not my choice...  the education system is just broken ....

Well thank you very much for this little explanation. Actually we found a way to temporally bypass this issue by turning the light off when making a selection. Still bug me that it'working on some and crash on others GPU...

Comment: @JonathanR: It's a driver issue and especially the AMD/ATI drivers are still very bug ridden, especially in seldomly used code paths.